# C++ Map Iterator to find most repeated word

Tags: c++

The program prints the most repeated word. How can I make it to print "---" if there are more than 2 words that are not the most repeated? Currently works on only 2 words.

> If the output is: 2 apple banana, print "---"
>
> Input: 5 apple apple banana apple banana
>
> Output: apple

How can I make it like this:

> Input: 4 apple apple banana banana
>
> Output: "---"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

void most_repeated_word(int n)
{
    using mmap = map<string, int>; mmap freq;
    string word;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> word;
        freq[word]++;
    }

    auto it = max_element(begin(freq), end(freq), []
    (const mmap::value_type& a, const mmap::value_type& b)
    { return a.second < b.second; });

    if ((it == end(freq)) || (it->second < 2))
        cout << "---" << endl;
    else
        cout << it->first << endl;
}

    int main() {

    int n;

    while (cin >> n) 
    {
        if (n < 1 && n > 100000) return 0;
        most_repeated_word(n);
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: "How can I make it to print "---" if there are more than 2 words that are not the most repeated?" not completely clear what you mean. In your example there is either `apple` or `banana` the most repeated, hence you dont have "more than 2 words that are not the most repeated"

Comment: @user463035818 The program will print "---" if there isn't a most repeated word. I'm asking how can I make it to work if the input is `apple apple banana banana` it will print `apple`, but it should print "---". Hope you understand.

Comment: so you want to print "---" if there is more than **one** word that is the most repeated, right?

Comment: @user463035818 Yes, it currently only works if the words are 2. Doesn't work if words are 4 `apple apple, banana banana`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the maximum, count the number of similarities elements:

```
auto value = it->second;
auto count = count_if(begin(freq), end(freq), [&]
    (const mmap::value_type& a)
    {return a.second == value;});
```

If you have more than 1 in `count`, print '---':

```
if (it->second < 2 || count != 1)
    cout << "---" << endl;
else
    cout << it->first << endl;
```

Comment: How do I implement it to my code. I can't find a way to make it work. Sorry if it's a stupid question.

Comment: `if(count >= 1)`, that's it, nothing more. The rest of the code can be used as is.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, I tried adding your code above instead of my if,else block, but it didn't work.

Comment: Modified my answer to add the if ;)